# How to get path of picture added by imagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift3

I try to get path of a picture added by imagePickerController (iOS, swift 3), and I have tried different ways, but every time, I get "nil"...

That's ways I've tried:

1.

```
if let picturePath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
    print(picturePath)
} else {
    print("Oh no...")
}
```

2.

```
let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as NSURL
let imageName = imageURL.path!.lastPathComponent
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as String
let localPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)
```

and 3.

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
let imageName         = imageUrl?.lastPathComponent
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)

if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localPath!.path) {
    do {
        try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)?.write(to: localPath!)
        print("file saved")
    }catch {
        print("error saving file")
    }
}
else {
    print("file already exists")
}
```

If you have an idea, I'll be glad to hear it!

Thank you,

Alexandre.

Comment: Images are stored in the user's Photo Library or Camera Roll, not in the apps `.documentDirectory` unless you store the picked image in that location. If you implement the delegate method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, then the `info` dictionary contains the picked image `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]`.

Comment: Hello,
I can get the image just after take it with the camera, but I'd like to get all image I've got in the app, so, I'd like to save the path of every image and the get back all image in another view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *add* a picture (i.e., take one with the camera), it is not automatically saved. You only get a UIImage, as you found out, by accessing `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]`.

You can for instance use [`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_:_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum) to save it to the camera roll or get a [JPEG representation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation) and save the returned `Data` anywhere you like in your documents folder (like your #3, but you have to come up with a filename yourself).

**Update**

Ok, here is how it works. Just to stress this point: in the image picker completion handler, you only get a `UIImage`. This image is not saved, yet, so there is no way to get an URL.

You can then

- Save it to your documents directory, to a path of your liking. This is implies that you choose a path/URL.
- Save it to the camera roll. In this case you will have to query the photo library for the URL it chose. The `completionSelector` of `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(...)` only tells you if it worked or if an error occured.

### Save to documents directory

```
func saveToDocuments(image: UIImage) -> URL throws
{
    let imageFolder = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let imageURL = imageFolder.appendingPathComponent("\(UUID()).jpg")
    let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
    try jpegData?.write(to: imageURL, options: .atomic)
    return imageURL
}
```

I chose a UUID as the (base) filename for simplification.

### Save to camera roll

You tell the photo library to create an asset and then query that asset to get the URL. I left out error handling for brevity.

```
func saveToCameraRoll(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
    var placeHolder: PHObjectPlaceholder? = nil
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let creationRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
        placeHolder = creationRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset!
    }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        guard success, let placeholder = placeHolder else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [placeholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
        guard let asset = assets.firstObject else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: { (editingInput, _) in
            completion(editingInput?.fullSizeImageURL)
        })
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
let image = UIImage(...)
saveToCameraRoll(image: image) { print("URL: \(String(describing: $0))") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know, but before to try to get the path of the image, I saved the image with:

```
let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img!, nil, nil, nil)
```

And then I try to get the path...

With my #3, I got this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Have you tried using the completionSelector of the writeToSavedPhotosAlbum-function? In the callback, you will be sure that the image was saved to the library, so you can for sure access it now? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum

Comment: If I don't try to get path of the image (#3), so, my image is saved in the library and I can access to it with "Photos" App

Comment: Are you sure the image is NOT nil? let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

Comment: If i write "let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage", my app don't crash. But if I write this:

(1) let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
(2) let imageName = imageUrl?.lastPathComponent
(3) let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
(4) let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
(1) and (2) is nil, but (3) and (4) is not nil...
My app crash with this line: (I guess because imageName is nil)
let localPath = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)